# Grab json response from api

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please check the controller bellow. I have to process the Json response inside this controller. My goal is to grab "success" value true or false. How can i access that value from following json response? I already tried to use JsSerialializer but no luck. Please check pictures for better understanding. Thanks in advance.

View Model:

```
public class GoogleRecaptcha
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public DateTime challenge_ts { get; set; }
    public string hostname { get; set; }
}
```

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

```
public ActionResult DownloadProcess()
{
    using (BlexzWebDbEntities db = new BlexzWebDbEntities())
    {
        //Validate Google recaptcha below
        var Response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
        string SecretKey = "6Lghu-MJoniMPXVf";

        //var client = new WebClient();

        var client = new RestClient("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddParameter("secret", SecretKey);
        request.AddParameter("response", Response);
        var ResultFromGoogle = client.Execute(request).Content;

        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var r = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(ResultFromGoogle);


        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Create a model containing those 3 properties (`bool success` etc) and deserialize the response to you model. - `var result = jsSerializer.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(ResultFromGoogle)`

Comment: i did same but getting error like this picture- https://ibb.co/jBSx0G and model was added. please check edited

Comment: Oop, sorry I pasted your without paying attention - its `jsSerializer.Deserialize<YourModel>(ResultFromGoogle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you want:

**1. Using JavaScriptSerializer with strongly typed model:**

```
public class ResultFromGoogle
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public DateTime Challenge_ts { get; set; }

    public string Hostname { get; set; }
}

ResultFromGoogle results = jsSerializer.Deserialize<ResultFromGoogle>(ResultFromGoogle);
var successValue = results.Success;
```

**2. Using JavaScriptSerializer without strongly typed model:**

```
var props = (Dictionary<string, object>)jsSerializer.DeserializeObject(ResultFromGoogle);
var successValue = props["success"];
```

**3. Using JSON.Net with strongly typed model:**

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultFromGoogle>();
var successValue = results.Success;
```

**4. Using JSON.Net without strongly typed model:**

```
var successValue = JObject.Parse(ResultFromGoogle).GetValue("success");
```

Overall, I suggest using strongly-typed model, because it provides conversion to required type (e.g. `bool` for `success` property and `DateTime` for `challenge_ts`). It's also more convenient if you need to access other fields of the response.

Json.Net in its turn is much more flexible than `JavaScriptSerializer`. You need to install [Json.Net NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to use options #3 and #4.